# Display N of N of N Items

Tags: javascript, php, math

I'm having some trouble with regards on my pagination script.
Currently I have the

`$total_item_count`, `$perPage`  and `$pageNo`.

How can I get the the first and last count of items that is being displayed to achive this

`Displaying $currentStart to $currentEnd of $total_item_count`

Here is what I have so far

```
$currentStart = (1 == $pageNo) ? 1 : 1 + $pageNo;
$currentEnd = ceil($perPage * $pageNo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
    $currentEnd = ($pageNo == $totalPages) ? $totalProducts : $perPage * $pageNo;
    $currentStart = ($pageNo == $totalPages) ? (($perPage * $pageNo - 1) - $perPage) + 2 : ($currentEnd - $perPage) + 1; 

    echo 'Displaying ' .$currentStart. ' - ' . $currentEnd . ' of ' .$totalProducts . ' items';
```